# AHAH Javascript callback

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-6, callback, ahah

Can we specify a Javascript function to be called after the AJAX request from a Drupal AHAH form is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a clean way to do this.

Try including a script element when returning html to be inserted in the dom.

Comment: Good idea. Works. But you are right. Not clean. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but you can use:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  // custom JS here
});
```